# Tinymce is not working in Rails project deployed on Heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I have a problem with the tinymce editor in my Rails 5 project.

It's working fine on my local environment but occurs error on Heroku.

```
Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html
```

Others are working fine but only tinymce doesn't work.

Please someone help me on this problem!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

My issue was because I placed tinymce stylesheet files to app/assets directory.

I moved them to public/assets directory and it worked fine for me.

Hope this helps!